# Add padding to elements in a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, padding

I am trying to create a grid `UIScrollView`, which so far is working great, I am just having a little trouble with adding 20px padding to both the width and height of the `UIImageView`s being displayed in the `UIScrollView``.

At the moment, I am adding 20px (`px` & `py`) to both the `x` and `y` values of the UIImageView's frame. However, this just moves the rows along 20px, and the columns down 20px. Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int w = 65;
int h = 65;
int c = 0;
int r = 0;
int px = 20;
int py = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.content count]; i++) {

    if (c < 4)
        c++;
    else if (c == 4) {
        c = 0;
        r++;
    }

    x = c * w;

    y = r * h;

    x += px;

    y += py;

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];

    [imageView setImage:[self.content objectAtIndex:i]];

    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

    [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    [imageView release];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the padding between each image, right?  As it stands, you're basically only adding it in once, at the very top.  Instead, add the padding, *then* multiply by the row and column.  Each image should be spaced out then.

EDIT to correct a silly mistake on my part.

```
x = c * (w + px);
y = r * (h + py);
```